# Select which chart data category to show versus omit

Tags: highcharts

In the following webpage, https://betterbuildingssolutioncenter.energy.gov/energy-data/District%20of%20Columbia , the highchart next to "Portfolio Energy Performance", clicking on the legend icon "Public" omits the public data and only shows the private data. How can I reverse this, so that clicking on the "Public" legend icon omits the private data instead? I have attached the code used for this webpage.

```js
// color declarations
var colorGreen = '#0b6a39',
    colorBlue = '#0c4489',
    colorBlueLight = '#558ed5',
    colorGray = '#595959',
    font = 'avenir';

// graph data variables
// Portfolio Energy Performance
var /* title */         energyPerformanceTitle = 'Average Annual % Improvement by Reporting Period',
        /* columns */           energyPerformanceCategories = ['2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019'],
        /* Y max */         energyPerformanceYMax = 9,
        /* X title */           energyPerformanceXaxis = [''],
        /* Y title */           energyPerformanceYaxis = ['Average Annual % Improvement'],
        /* column colors */     energyPerformanceColumns = [colorBlue, colorBlue, colorBlue, colorBlue, colorBlue, colorBlue, colorBlue, colorBlue],
        /* column data */       energyPerformanceData = [8.53, 3.31, 2.37, 2.91, 2.86, 2.63, 2.4, 0.34],
        /* goal data */     energyPerformanceGoalData = 2;

// Energy Performance by Facility
var /* title */         energyFacilityTitle = 'Number of Properties by Cumulative % Improvement',
        /* columns */           energyFacilityCategories = ['&lt;=0%', '0-2%', '2-6%', '6-10%', '10-15%', '>15%'],
        /* X title */           energyFacilityXaxis = ['Cumulative % Improvement Category'],
        /* Y title */           energyFacilityYaxis = ['Number of Properties'],
        /* Y interval */        energyFacilityYinterval = 10,
        /* column colors */     energyFacilityColumns = [colorBlue, colorGreen, colorGreen, colorGreen, colorGreen, colorGreen, colorGreen],
        /* column data */       energyFacilityData = [82, 14, 28, 16, 35, 101];

// Identifying Opportunities for Improvement
var /* title */         improvementOpportunityTitle = '% Improvement vs. Baseline EUI',
        /* columns */           improvementOpportunityCategories = ['0', '200', '400', '600', '800'],
        /* X min */         improvementOpportunityXMin = 0,
        /* X max */         improvementOpportunityXMax = 800,
        /* Y min */         improvementOpportunityYMin = -60,
        /* Y max */         improvementOpportunityYMax = 100,
        /* Y interval */        improvementOpportunityYinterval = 20,
        /* X interval */        improvementOpportunityXinterval = 200,
        /* X title */           improvementOpportunityXaxis = ['Baseline Source EUI (kBtu/sq.ft.)'],
        /* Y title */           improvementOpportunityYaxis = ['% Improvement'],
        /* scatter data */      improvementOpportunityData = [[704,76], [55,-273], [216,10], [205,6], [505,12], [167,4], [147,-7], [254,-14], [307,19], [275,36], [179,-4], [146,-16], [324,17], [225,19], [146,5], [199,18], [162,4], [183,26], [208,20], [187,-13], [187,19], [145,49], [172,24], [206,25], [208,-35], [222,16], [221,19], [145,18], [151,10], [159,-13], [221,20], [150,26], [215,38], [152,11], [158,-17], [174,9], [249,28], [166,12], [231,3], [165,15], [132,16], [217,3], [163,1], [225,3], [151,20], [149,-9], [164,5], [149,-3], [193,30], [177,10], [246,-20], [155,4], [184,17], [200,7], [132,10], [162,12], [149,19], [252,23], [142,-16], [165,10], [230,-2], [180,16], [193,29], [185,5], [61,49], [226,66], [128,46], [141,76], [190,2], [194,24], [217,10], [127,3], [216,15], [89,-23], [137,-9], [162,33], [171,7], [136,19], [190,-6], [155,18], [93,-35], [147,-20], [199,7], [141,14], [177,7], [276,-16], [103,-2], [172,20], [90,-24], [153,17], [184,10], [149,34], [240,-5], [163,-15], [122,-10], [160,-22], [236,16], [139,5], [183,22], [165,12], [141,22], [114,-39], [175,16], [164,26], [141,16], [186,28], [160,-14], [148,14], [231,15], [204,-9], [170,6], [112,-4], [170,27], [191,17], [216,-1], [215,12], [166,19], [131,-13], [109,15], [181,4], [300,28], [210,13], [236,15], [183,19], [144,14], [198,3], [219,-14], [291,12], [169,19], [194,-8], [208,-16], [304,3], [208,0], [195,-5], [175,17], [143,-1], [161,15], [194,-10], [121,-3], [117,21], [189,0], [136,10], [189,-7], [150,-32], [308,-1], [136,-1], [253,-2], [121,25], [427,2], [222,20], [150,-2], [254,33], [284,38], [307,3], [249,26], [178,6], [134,-22], [282,-4], [151,-10], [143,-3], [116,-6], [158,7], [161,16], [260,55], [131,15], [246,3], [113,-3], [209,22], [322,21], [245,39], [197,14], [142,5], [253,23], [197,-9], [184,15], [169,12], [187,12], [132,-21], [195,16], [143,6], [145,-10], [200,35], [142,5], [178,28], [271,21], [140,-29], [125,6], [148,-15], [185,18], [163,36], [173,13], [117,-2], [291,23], [168,-8], [196,26], [202,13], [169,22], [142,-37], [142,-32], [211,22], [165,5], [181,30], [140,0], [126,-15], [410,14], [167,-17], [205,13], [171,-6], [197,24], [167,15], [115,0], [160,31], [164,13], [176,11], [169,23], [153,25], [542,16], [138,-12], [143,-25], [228,-1], [95,10], [147,-14], [200,8], [195,1], [178,12], [192,20], [152,11], [224,1], [150,-2], [247,12], [208,36], [134,-18], [231,-4], [248,-1], [217,-2], [164,22], [288,0], [201,15], [149,26], [206,33], [179,23], [151,22], [168,14], [165,5], [176,12], [145,-15], [103,-40], [163,5], [141,-9], [128,9], [177,30], [238,17], [182,10], [198,23], [147,-8], [205,29], [528,-8], [205,16], [164,15], [163,39], [193,1], [173,-1], [168,30], [233,6], [117,2], [205,13], [110,7], [161,15], [159,4], [197,2], [131,0], [231,-37], [248,0], [140,0], [155,-9], [153,-2],],
        /* trendline data */    improvementOpportunityTrendLine = [[55, -5], [704, 54]];

// On document ready, call visualize on the datatable.
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    Highcharts.visualize = function (table, options) {
        // the categories
        options.xAxis.categories = energyPerformanceCategories;
        options.colors = energyPerformanceColumns,
            options.series = [{
                type: 'column',
                name: ['Public'],
                data: energyPerformanceData,
                color: colorBlue,
                colorByPoint: false,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }, {
                type: 'column',
                name: ['Private'],
                data: [3.3, 4.95, 3.68, 3.31, 2.76, 2.99, 2.3, 1.71],
                color: colorBlueLight,
                colorByPoint: false,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },

            }];
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }

    var table = document.getElementById('datatable'),
        options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'energy-performance',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: energyPerformanceTitle,
                style: {
                    color: colorGray,
                    fontFamily: font
                }
            },
            subtitle: {},
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    shadow: false
                },
                column: {
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: energyPerformanceXaxis,
                    style: {
                        color: colorGray,
                        fontFamily: font
                    }
                },
                tickLength: 0,
                lineColor: colorGray,
                lineWidth: 1
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Average Annual % Improvement',
                    style: {
                        color: colorGray,
                        fontFamily: font
                    }
                },
                tickInterval: 1,
                tickLength: 5,
                tickWidth: 1,
                tickColor: colorGray,
                max: energyPerformanceYMax,
                lineColor: colorGray,
                lineWidth: 1,
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                plotLines: [{
                    color: colorGray,
                    width: 2,
                    value: energyPerformanceGoalData,
                    zIndex: 5,
                    label: {
                        text: 'GOAL',
                        align: 'right',
                        x: 11,
                        y: -5,
                        style: {
                            color: colorGray,
                            fontFamily: font,
                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                        }
                    }
                }],
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        color: colorGray,
                        fontFamily: font
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true
            },
            legend: {
                itemHiddenStyle: {
                  color: colorBlue,
                  colorByPoint: false
                }
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    var raw = ((this.y / energyPerformanceData[0])) * 100,
                        percentage = Math.round(100 - (raw * 100) / 100);
                    if (this.y === energyPerformanceData[0] && this.key === '2012') {
                        return '<strong>' + this.series.name + '</strong><br/>' + '<strong>' + this.x + '</strong>: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 1) + '%';
                    } else {
                        return '<strong>' + this.series.name + '</strong><br/>' + '<strong>' + this.x + '</strong>: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 1) + '%';
                    }
                },
            }
        };
    Highcharts.visualize(table, options);
});

// On document ready, call visualize on the datatable.
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    Highcharts.visualize = function (table, options) {
        // the categories
        options.xAxis.categories = energyFacilityCategories;
        options.colors = energyFacilityColumns,
            options.series = [{
                type: 'column',
                name: energyFacilityYaxis,
                data: energyFacilityData,
                color: colorGreen,
                colorByPoint: true,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }];
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }

    var table = document.getElementById('datatable'),
        options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'facility-performance',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: energyFacilityTitle,
                style: {
                    color: colorGray,
                    fontFamily: font
                }
            },
            subtitle: {},
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    shadow: false
                },
                column: {
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: energyFacilityXaxis,
                    style: {
                        color: colorGray,
                        fontFamily: font
                    }
                },
                tickLength: 0,
                lineColor: colorGray,
                lineWidth: 1,
                labels: {
                    rotation: -45,
                    y: 30,
                    style: {
                        color: colorGray,
                        fontFamily: font
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: energyFacilityYaxis,
                    style: {
                        color: colorGray,
                        fontFamily: font
                    }
                },
                tickInterval: energyFacilityYinterval,
                tickLength: 5,
                tickWidth: 1,
                tickColor: colorGray,
                lineColor: colorGray,
                lineWidth: 1,
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                minorTickColor: colorGray,
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        color: colorGray,
                        fontFamily: font
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<strong>' + this.series.name + '</strong><br/>' + '<strong>' + this.x + '</strong>: ' + this.y;
                }
            }
        };
    Highcharts.visualize(table, options);
});

// On document ready, call visualize on the datatable.
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    Highcharts.visualize = function (table, options) {
        // the categories
        options.xAxis.categories = improvementOpportunityCategories;
        options.series = [{
            name: improvementOpportunityYaxis,
            data: improvementOpportunityData,
            color: colorBlue
        }, {
            type: 'line',
            name: 'Trendline',
            data: improvementOpportunityTrendLine,
            color: colorGray,
            width: 1,
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }];
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }

    var table = document.getElementById('datatable'),
        options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'improvement-opportunities',
                type: 'scatter',
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            title: {
                text: improvementOpportunityTitle,
                style: {
                    color: colorGray,
                    fontFamily: font
                }
            },
            subtitle: {},
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    shadow: false
                },
                scatter: {
                    marker: {
                        radius: 3,
                        symbol: 'diamond',
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            marker: {
                                enabled: false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: improvementOpportunityXaxis,
                    style: {
                        color: colorGray,
                        fontFamily: font
                    }
                },
                lineWidth: 0,
                min: improvementOpportunityXMin,
                max: improvementOpportunityXMax,
                tickInterval: improvementOpportunityXinterval,
                minTickInterval: 25,
                tickLength: 0
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: improvementOpportunityYaxis,
                    style: {
                        color: colorGray,
                        fontFamily: font
                    }
                },
                min: improvementOpportunityYMin,
                max: improvementOpportunityYMax,
                tickInterval: improvementOpportunityYinterval,
                tickLength: 5,
                tickWidth: 1,
                tickColor: colorGray,
                lineColor: colorGray,
                lineWidth: 1,
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                plotLines: [{
                    color: colorGray,
                    width: 1,
                    value: 0
                }, {
                    color: colorGray,
                    width: 1,
                    value: 0,
                    zIndex: 5
                }]
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<strong>' + this.series.name + ':</strong> ' + this.y;
                }
            }
        };
    Highcharts.visualize(table, options);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `legendItemClick` event and hide/show other series than the clicked one:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function() {
                    this.chart.series.forEach(function(s) {
                        if (s !== this) {
                            s.setVisible();
                        }
                    }, this);

                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j0eyc625/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setVisible

Comment: Also, how do I prevent the chart from going blank/showing no data when I click on "public" and then "private" (or vice versa)? @ppotaczek

Comment: Hi @Karen Wu, You can check if the clicked series is visible. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/csgj927h/

Comment: Do you know where in the code to change the legend icon dot for "Public" to be dark blue instead of its current grey color?  @ppotaczek

Comment: Use `legend.itemHiddenStyle` property. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vj98h1L7/

Comment: After adding " legend: {
                itemHiddenStyle: {
                  color: colorBlue
                }" starting on line 148, the "Private" legend icon dot now turns blue when I click on it. How can I keep it light blue after clicking on it? Also, how do I fade the legend icon when I click on the other data category? For example, to fade the "Public" legend icon when I click on the "Private" legend icon. @ppotaczek

Comment: Hi @Karen Wu, Could you recreate your current state in jsfiddle?

Comment: I just updated the javascript code in my original posting question to its current state. Can you identify the issue(s) now? Thank you for your help! @ppotaczek

Comment: I am unable to run your code. Please use the simple example provided by me, and adapt it to show the problem.

Comment: Are you able to run my code on this separate question I just posted (same question): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69275841/highcharts-legend-data-interactivity-issues ? @ppotaczek

Comment: Yes, thanks, here is the live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x6gctham/ To prevent changing color behaviour, you can wrap `colorizeItem` method. You can also use `legendItemClick` event to hide/show legend items. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8j9bonxp/

Comment: In the second example you show in your most recent comment, how can I get the "Public" data to show when I click on the "Public" legend icon (and vice versa)? Currently, your example shows "Private" data when I click on "Public". Also, in your example, how can I prevent the legend label from turning light gray when I click on it? @ppotaczek

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/frmekwhn/ ?

Comment: That is perfect, thank you so much for your help! @ppotaczek